# What are F#'s FSharp.Core.optdata and FSharp.Core.sigdata files?

Tags: .net, f#

Both files seem to reside in F#'s directory, along with FSharp.Core.dll. 
Both files seem to be a constant source of trouble if one forgets to put them together with FSharp.Core.dll. 
They seem to be binary files so I wasn't able to uncover their purpose.

I googled a bit both files but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer to my question. So..what is their function in F#?

Comment: I think it is related to optimization data and might be suppressed by `--nooptimizationdata`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true. I was having application crashes without those both files, so I put them in the output directory. I tried running it with that flag and no files and it crashed again. :(

Comment: These are so weird. I just made an F# NuGet package with FSharp.Core.dll included. If the package is used in an F# library project, that project won't compile unless the .sigdata and .optdata files are included (in the NuGet package). However, only FSharp.Core.dll and **not** the sig/optdata files are included in the library's release directory, and everything runs fine without them.

In this case, it seems they are only needed during compilation.

Comment: The .sigdata file seems to contain references to some .fsi files, while the .optdata file seems to reference .fs files and concrete types in them. Don't know, however, what is their purpose :( Optimization, maybe, as stated by others.

Comment: There are many F# type system features which can't be expressed directly on the CLR - things like whether a type is a discriminated union or record type, inline definitions and statically resolved type parameters, and information about how functions are curried (e.g. `let f (x,y) z = x + y+ z` might be compiled into a method with three parameters, but from F# it needs to appear to take a tuple and another curried argument.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Optdata is definitely optimisation data, it is written as part of the `EncodeOptimizationData` function in the compiler.  `FSharp.Core` has this information stored in an external file rather than embedded in the resource manifest.

sigdata is encoded with `EncodeInterfaceData` and contains information about the signatures/interfaces for the F# types.  `FSharp.Core`, `FSharp.Compiler.Silverlight` and `FSharp.LanguageService.Compiler` all have this information stored in an external file rather than embedded in the resource manifest.

As `FSharp.Core` does not contain either of these in its resource manifest they have to be present externally, Im not sure of this reason though.

User produced F# files, when compiled, have this information encoded into the resource manifest, you can see this if you look at the metadata.

Comment: Right. In other words, `SigData` and `OptData` are always compiled into F# assemblies as managed resources, unless you specify a flag like `--nooptimizationdata`. I'm not sure why, but `FSharp.Core` dumps these resources into external files (`FSharp.Core.sigdata` and `FSharp.Core.optdata`); when you try to compile an F# project which references another F# assembly (e.g., `FSharp.Core`) the F# compiler needs that information -- if it's not embedded into the referenced assembly as a managed resource, it looks for the external files. If it can't find either, compilation fails with an error.