# How to conditionally inline members in F#, or switch off inlining in Debug builds altogether

Tags: debugging, f#, visual-studio-2015, inline, f#-4.0

I can't readily remember where I read it, but my understanding of inline was that it is "switched off" (except for statically resolving type constraints) during debug builds. But it isn't, a breakpoint on an inline member is never hit and *stepping into* is not possible.

Since there is a (slight) semantic difference between using inline and not using it, perhaps this is the reason that inlining is also enforced in debug builds? For inline functions that I do want to investigate during debugging I currently use something like this:

Original code:

```
type CE =
    static member inline map f = CE.bind (f >> Some)   // line is never hit
```

Updated code

```
type CE =
    static member 
#if !DEBUG
            inline 
#endif
                map f =
        CE.bind (f >> Some)    // gets hit now when debugging
```

While this works, it is ugly. Is there another possibility, i.e. with a compiler switch or attribute, to turn this on/off, or is that asking for too much trouble (i.e. the earlier mentioned statically resolved type parameters, and perhaps the auto-inlining of user-defined operators).

Note: my primary use-case is actually not debugging per se, but hit-counting of the functions or members, and in lieu of that, code-coverage reports.

Using F# 4.0, .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I don't think that `inline` could be switched off completely in debug build because compiler uses it for type resolution. You can play however with `--nooptimizationdata` compiler switch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx

Comment: @Petr, I just tried that flag, but it seems to have no effect, the inlined members are still inlined. Perhaps `--nooptimizationdata` only skips the [optdata and sigdata files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224314/what-are-fs-fsharp-core-optdata-and-fsharp-core-sigdata-files)?

Comment: This is a complicated issue.  I tend to think of `inline` functions as similar to using `#define f(arg)...` in C, which seems to map reasonably closely with what actualy happens and suggests what you want is difficult

Comment: @JohnPalmer, I don't think it needs to be difficult (from a compiler-writing perspective). The compiler could create a wrapper function with the same signature of the inlined function and inline the wrapper function, which itself calls the non-inlined function. For this particular module (of which I wanted to know the test-coverage) I have added a `NOINLINE` compiler directive and added a slightly more readable `#if !NOINLINE` to each function I want to measure. The build server now has a separate run for code coverage with `NOINLINE` specified. I have yet to run into compilation errors.

Comment: I guess I meant difficult in general, for your specific case, where `inline` is only their for speed, it is fine, but there are places where inline is not optional - generic numeric code etc.  Also, some library functions are inline which could make things very difficult for coverage

Comment: @JohnPalmer, agreed, which is why the `#if...` approach only has limited value and the wrapper-function approach _could_ be used (I think) – if available – with those cases where static type constraints are required. _As an aside, it looks like the answer to my q. is "cannot be done presently"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a real issue with not following inline directives in several cases. The F# core library offers functions, including the [(+) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340262.aspx), which require the use of [statically-resolved type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx), as you noted in your question. The CLR's generics runtime system doesn't support these types of generics. Instead, the F# compiler is inferring the generic type arguments at compile time and creating the IL necessary to execute for each type that was resolved.

This is a key feature and makes ignoring all `inline` directives a general non-starter since in many cases it means code won't compile. `--nooptimizationdata` generally removes optimization data from the generated assembly; it doesn't prevent inlining within the assembly, but it may inhibit other assemblies from inlining when referencing `inline` functions.

It should also be noted that Don Syme has stated that use of `inline` is not often required (outside of the SRTP) and may be a premature performance optimization that may actually get in the way of the compiler doing its own optimization.

Comment: Apologies for this late response, apparently I totally missed your answer, but it is correct and I agree to your analysis that allowing it to be switched off would be a non-starter.

Comment: If it can not be done for all inline functions It would be nice if there was an option to switch inline functions for a file