# Embedding F# Interactive Example Throwing Exception from FSharp.Compiler.Service

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am working through the Embedding F# Interactive example from http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html but am having an issue with the following line throwing an exception:

```
let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)
```

The exception thrown is:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll
Additional information: Error creating evaluation session: StopProcessing null"

My project is being run from VS2015 Enterprise Update 1, setup as a simple F# console app,  with Target F# runtime being F# 4.0 with the Target Framework as 4.6.  The version of FSharp.Compiler.Service downloaded from nuget is 2.0.0.2.

The Program.Fs file code I am running is here (a direct port of the example):

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Text
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let sbOut = new StringBuilder()
    let sbErr = new StringBuilder()
    let inStream = new StringReader("")
    let outStream = new StringWriter(sbOut)
    let errStream = new StringWriter(sbErr)

    // Build command line arguments & start FSI session
    let argv = [| "C:\\fsi.exe" |]
    let allArgs = Array.append argv [|"--noninteractive"|]

    let fsiConfig = FsiEvaluationSession.GetDefaultConfiguration()
    let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)

    /// Evaluate expression & return the result
    let evalExpression text =
        match fsiSession.EvalExpression(text) with
        | Some value -> printfn "%A" value.ReflectionValue
        | None -> printfn "Got no result!"

    evalExpression "42+1" // prints '43'

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

    0  // return integer
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: [What are F#'s FSharp.Core.optdata and FSharp.Core.sigdata files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224314/what-are-fs-fsharp-core-optdata-and-fsharp-core-sigdata-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to your problem is found at [Compiler Services: Notes on FSharp.Core.dll](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/corelib.html)

> If doing dynamic compilation and execution you may also need to
>   include an FSharp.Core.optdata and FSharp.Core.sigdata, see below for
>   guidance.

When you build the application the output directory with `FSharp.Core.dll` is missing two files:

```
FSharp.Core.optdata  
FSharp.Core.sigdata
```

You will need to find these two files and the correct versions of the files that agree with FSharp.Core.dll and copy them to the build output directory.

**How to find the files using Visual Studio**

From menu View -> Solution Explorer
Expand Project
Expand References
Right click FSharp.Core and select properties.

[image]

The Full Path gives the directory that should have at least the three files.
Use a file explorer to open the directory in Full Path.

[image]

Copy the two files

```
FSharp.Core.optdata  
FSharp.Core.sigdata
```

to the build directory.

**How to find the build directory using Visual Studio**

From menu View -> Solution Explorer
Select Project
Press F4 to open the Properties Page

[image]

The Project Folder with `\bin\Debug` is the default when debugging with VS.

**Change location of fsi.exe**

Now that you have the two needed files you will also need to change the location of fsi.exe

```
let argv = [| "C:\\fsi.exe" |]
```

because I doubt that fsi.exe is in the root of your C drive.

Comment: Great explanation, but I still got the same error after copying the files.