# Embedding F# Interactive throw System.Exception: 'Error creating evaluation session: StopProcessingExn None'

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-interactive, .net-core-2.0

I'm working through the Embedding F# Interactive example from [here](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html) but like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34858591/5154345), I'm having an issue with the following line throwing an exception:

```
let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)
```

The exception thrown is:

"System.Exception: 'Error creating evaluation session: StopProcessingExn None'"

My project is being run from VS2017 Enterprise, setup as a simple F# console app, with the Target Framework as `.NET Core 2.0`. The version of `FSharp.Compiler.Service` downloaded from nuget is 17.0.1 and `FSharp.Core` is 4.2.0.

The Program.Fs file code I'm running is here (a direct port of the example):

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Text
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let sbOut = new StringBuilder()
    let sbErr = new StringBuilder()
    let inStream = new StringReader("")
    let outStream = new StringWriter(sbOut)
    let errStream = new StringWriter(sbErr)

    // Build command line arguments & start FSI session
    let argv = [| "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\F#\\4.1\\Framework\\v4.0\\fsi.exe" |]
    let allArgs = Array.append argv [|"--noninteractive"|]

    let fsiConfig = FsiEvaluationSession.GetDefaultConfiguration()
    let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)

    /// Evaluate expression & return the result
    let evalExpression text =
        match fsiSession.EvalExpression(text) with
        | Some value -> printfn "%A" value.ReflectionValue
        | None -> printfn "Got no result!"

    evalExpression "42+1" // prints '43'

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

    0  // return integer
```

I already tried to add the files `FSharp.Core.optdata` and `FSharp.Core.sigdata` in my bin folder (bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34858591/5154345) and [here](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/corelib.html), but without success. By the way, my bin folder does not contain the file `FSharp.Core.dll`.

I also tried to publish my app and add the `.optdata` and `.sigdata` files manually in the publish folder, but without success either.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think fsi is supported in dotnetcore yet.

Comment: @s952163 do you have any links or more information to confirm that?

Comment: This is still open: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2407 Best would be to ping someone on the #dotnetcore channel in the FSSF [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/)

Comment: For the record, I also found this issue on GitHub : https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/issues/807