# FSharp.Core.optdata not found alongside FSharp.Core

Tags: f#

I have a C# program that call this F# code snipet. On executing `let fsiSession` I get the exception below. These [site](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/corelib.html) hint at some ideas, but I don't understand what they are saying. I have no idea where FSharp.Core.optdata is found.

```
namespace FsharpTestgSystem

open System
open System.IO
open System.Text

open System.CodeDom
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SimpleSourceCodeServices


type TestSystem() =
    // Intialize output and input streams
    // Build command line arguments & start FSI session
    let argv = [| "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\F#\\4.1\\Framework\\v4.0\\fsi.exe" |]
    let allArgs = Array.append argv [|"--noninteractive"|]

    let sbOut = new StringBuilder()
    let sbErr = new StringBuilder()
    let inStream = new StringReader("")
    let outStream = new StringWriter(sbOut)
    let errStream = new StringWriter(sbErr)
    let fsiConfig = FsiEvaluationSession.GetDefaultConfiguration()
    let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)

unknown(1,1): error FS1225: File '\bin\x64\Debug\FSharp.Core.optdata' not found alongside FSharp.Core
unknown(1,1): error FS0229: Error opening binary ...
```

Comment: It's saying that it should be in the SDK directory. [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224314/what-are-fs-fsharp-core-optdata-and-fsharp-core-sigdata-files/) Btw, the only place I was able to find this file was in Fake/tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put in direct references to the below for some utilities I wrote that need things in these namespaces:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Settings.dll

Probably you can pass a reference to this file to the process that is getting spawned with an extra argument. See --reference over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options.

Note: the command arguments for Fsi tend to be the same as those for Fsc.exe

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on my old project after installing VS 2017. What fixed it for me was:

- Make a backup of all files.
- Install latest version of FSharp.Core from nuget (happens to be 4.2.1 right now)
- In project properties:

  - Select latest version of F# as Target Runtime, which happened to be 4.4.1.0.
  - Select .NET Framework 4.7 as Target Framework.

Comment: I suspect I'm having the same issue but with VS 2019. Why is F# team not finding a definitive solution?

Comment: At least in my case the upgrade of .NET Framework to 4.7 was not needed in the end. And I used bindingRedirect to keep even the old FSharp.Core that was in production a few years ago

Answer (score 0):

I need FSharp.Core 3, so I'm doing some archaeology today. The optdata and sigdata files are not provided by Paket, but they are available in the nupkg available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/3.1.2.5).